# apollo-cache-persist with vue-apollo in nuxt

Tags: caching, async-await, nuxt.js, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I'm trying to use `apollo-cache-persist` but I am confused by the docs: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist/blob/master/README.md#web.

This is the web initialization code:

```
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { persistCache } from 'apollo-cache-persist';

const cache = new InMemoryCache({...});

// await before instantiating ApolloClient, else queries might run before the cache is persisted
await persistCache({
  cache,
  storage: window.localStorage,
});
```

`await persistCache()` is throwing an error and I don't understand how it would work without async.  I'm guessing that I need to put this in a plugin but I'm not quite sure how to do that either.

See this other question for more of the Apollo Client configuration: [@client Apollo GQL tag breaks query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780294/client-apollo-gql-tag-breaks-query).

Answer (score 1):

i am not up to date on nuxt.js.

Look at [vue-cli-plugin-ssr](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-cli-plugin-ssr) from the author of `vue-apollo`. it is modifying `main.js` by wrapping `new Vue(...)` with `export async function createApp` with beforeApp, afterApp async callbacks, for restoring cache sent by server. you could just `vue add @akryum/ssr` and you will find a place to put your async hooks in `entry-client.js` after thinking about a proper way of merging client and server cache...

or you could do something simpler:

```js
// vue-apollo.js
import { persistCache } from 'apollo-cache-persist'
export async function willCreateProvider() {
  await persistCache({ cache, storage: window.localStorage })
}

export function createProvider(options = {}) { }
```

```js
// main.js
import { createProvider, willCreateProvider } from './vue-apollo'
willCreateProvider().then(() => {
  new Vue({
    router,
    apolloProvider: createProvider(),
    render: h => h(App),
  }).$mount('#app')
})
```

There is also `persistCacheSync` in [`apollo-cache-persist-dev@^0.2.0`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-cache-persist-dev)